# Unable to get data using xpath on dynamic webpage using importxml google sheets

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to pull out data, for example the 24kt gold price for Singapore, and every time sheet gives out an error "#N/A" in google sheets with the `=IMPORTXML` function

This is the site am trying to pull the information from "https://www.malabargoldanddiamonds.com/ae/goldprice"

Below are some function which I wrote to pull out the value and nothing seems to work for me

```
=importxml("https://www.malabargoldanddiamonds.com/ae/goldprice", "//td[@id='price24t_85']")

=importxml("https://www.malabargoldanddiamonds.com/ae/goldprice", "//*[@id='price24t_85']")

=importxml("https://www.malabargoldanddiamonds.com/ae/goldprice", "//div[contains(@class, 'goldrate_FarEast')]//td[@id='price24t_85']")
```

Would you shed some light on this.

Comment: The link to the website doesn't work, it appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Fixed the website now.

Comment: Could you post the accepted answer? I would like to know.